# set minRequiredPasswordLength in custom membership with web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, membership-provider

i have *CustomMembership* class in project and use this code in class:

```
private static int _MinRequiredPasswordLength;
public static int MinRequiredPasswordLength
    {
        set { _MinRequiredPasswordLength = value; }
        get { return _MinRequiredPasswordLength; }
    }
```

and set membership in web.config

```
<membership defaultProvider="CustomMembership">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="CustomMembership" type="Project1.Code.CustomMembership, Project1, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral" connectionStringName="PConn" enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false" maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

and use this code for get minRequiredPasswordLength:

```
MinRequiredPasswordLength.Text = CMembership.MinRequiredPasswordLength.ToString();
```

but get '0'! I want get '6'.

Answer (score 2):

If you've derived from the abstract `MembershipProvider` class, you should override `MembershipProvider.Initialize`.  The `config` collection will contain all the configuration attributes, and you can use them to set your properties including `MinRequiredPasswordLength`:

```
private int _minRequiredPasswordLength;

public override void Initialize(string name, NameValueCollection config)
{
    _minRequiredPasswordLength = // get it from config["minRequiredPasswordLength"], with validation and conversion to int.
}

public override MinRequiredPasswordLength
{
    get { return _minRequiredPasswordLength; }
}
```

If you've derived from an existing provider, e.g. `SqlMembershipProvider`, then you can simply use the base class implementation of `MinRequiredPasswordLength`.

Comment: help me for get it from config["minRequiredPasswordLength"].

Comment: @shahinko - basically you use `Int32.TryParse` to parse config["minRequiredPasswordLength"].  Then decide what you want to do if the configuration parameter is not present, or is not a valid integer - probably you'll want to throw a ProviderException or a ConfigurationErrorsException.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
MinRequiredPasswordLength.Text = @CustomMembership.MinRequiredPasswordLength
```

Comment: You have '0' because you never set value for you public property `MinRequiredPasswordLength`

Comment: I set this in web.config